# How is the 'i' variable being incremented in this loop?

Tags: scala

Below code prints 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

```
for (i <- 0 until 10) {
    println(i)
```

How is the var 'i' being incremented ? I suspect there is something implicit occurring but inspecting the signature of 'until' which returns a Range I dont know what this is ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`for` in scala is not a loop, but something called a `comprehension`. In your case it simply calls `Range.foreach`, because `0 until 10` creates a `Range`. It then just recursively calls the function you pass to the foreach for each value in the range.

**edit**:

Depending on how exactly your `for` looks, it will create nested calls to `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, `filter`...

E.g:

```
for {
  x <- 0 until 10
  y <- 0 until 10
} yield x * y
```

Will be compiled to

```
(0 until 10) flatMap { x =>
  (0 until 10) map { y =>
    x*y
  }
}
```

and

```
for {
  x <- 0 until 10
  if x % 2 == 0
} yield x * 2
```

will be compiled to something like

```
(0 until 10).filter { x =>
  x % 2 == 0
}.map { x =>
  x * 2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`for` is interpreted as a `foreach` method over a collection in Scala. So what is really executed is

```
(0 until 10) foreach { i => println(i) }
```

As you mentioned, `until` takes 2 integers and returns a `Range`, which is a sequence {0,1,2,...,9}. Your program goes over each of these 10 numbers and apply function `println` to it. In one word, the underlying implementation of `for` is in a functional-programming style, where there is no need to do increment.

Answer (score 3):

0 until 10 defines a range.

The for comprehension gets expanded into the following:

```
(0 until 10) foreach { println(_) }
```

Which, after the range is expanded is similar to:

```
(Seq(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)) foreach { println(_) }
```

Comment: `Range` gets never expanded to a `Seq` containing all the elements (if you mean that with "expanded").

Comment: @sschaef - That's why I said similar. I know it's not an exact translation.

Answer (score 0):

`until` is a method - invoked in infix notation - that returns a [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range). The `for` look is basically an iteration over this `Range`. This is a different notation of the same thing:

```
0.until(10).foreach(println(_))
```